# Finding consciousness through EEG

Tags: consciousness, eeg, fmri

I've read an article about the consciousness in vegetative patients. [Adrian Owen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_Owen) is one of the neuroscientist making research on this field. The article published on "Le scienze" was about the usage of fMRI before and EEG later, to check the presence of a consciousness.

Do you know of similar group of research in Italy? 
Is their work consolidated enough to be applied in the clinical practice by another neurologist?

Comment: "in Italy" is a bit specific, is there a reason you're looking for groups in Italy in particular?

Comment: You'll have to be more precise. Consciousness is a broad term. There is a bunch of research on, for example, detecting if a nonresponsive patient is minimally conscious or in deep coma, often using EEG. Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: @Seanny123: yes, one of my relative had a stroke.. most of doctors are simply following a protocol which will evolve in the next 50 years. Not the newest technologies.. I would like to try to help him.

Comment: @jona: He is suspected to be in locked in syndrome. And seems to execute simple commands. But I would like to investigate it better. Does he feel pain? Does he understands completely? Is he ready for rehabilitation? If you have any advice I would really appreciate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any such group in Italy but there is a group in Liege, Belgium which is called Coma Science Group. It consists of scientists of various disciplines and their main interest is understanding disorders of consciousness. Also their work has a clinical orientation as well. From your description, I think it will be interesting to you. Their website is http://www.coma.ulg.ac.be